# uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::Aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, aws-sdk

I'm working on a Rails 5.1 web application. I use the Paperclip and aws_sdk gem's for file uploads:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'aws_sdk', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'
```

but when I run my application, I get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error - uninitialized constant 
Paperclip::Storage::S3::Aws:
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:125:in `extended'
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:428:in `extend'
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:428:in 
`initialize_storage'
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:90:in `initialize'
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:47:in `new'
  paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:47:in `block in 
define_instance_getter'
```

Is anyone familiar with this error?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a version issue.

I downgraded aws_sdk to version 2.3.0 and now it's working!